# sequelize findOrCreate doesn't return array

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Stuck with Sequelize `findOrCreate` method. 

So i'm expecting to get empty array of `tags`, but i'm getting `tag.id, tag.name ...` etc.

```
[ { id: 2,
    name: 'Inf 1',
    email: 'andrew@ww.rt',
    createdAt: 2017-10-24T16:30:38.314Z,
    updatedAt: 2017-10-24T16:31:02.076Z,
    category_id: null,
    'tags.id': null, <---- Here is should be just like tags: []` 
    'tags.name': null,
    'tags.description': null,
    'tags.createdAt': null,
    'tags.updatedAt': null,
    'tags.UsersTags.createdAt': null,
    'tags.UsersTags.updatedAt': null,
    'tags.UsersTags.user_id': null,
    'tags.UsersTags.tag_id': null },
  false ]
```

**Model usage**

```
User.findOrCreate({
    raw: true,
    where: query,
    defaults: update,
    include: [{
      model: Model.Tag,
      as: 'tags'
    }]
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use

```
User.findOrCreate({
    raw: true,
    where: query,
    defaults: update,
    include: [{
      model: Model.Tag,
      as: 'tags',
      required: false // <-- thanks to this will return null if none is joined
    }]
  })
```

Refs: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#nested-eager-loading